# How to fix "Document Loading Fail" in Nextcloud

Tags: docker, docker-compose, libreoffice, nextcloud

I am trying to setup my local Nextcloud suite with a local collabora server using the fallowing docker-compose file:

```
 version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.32
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: nextcloud
      MYSQL_DATABASE: nextcloud
      MYSQL_USER: nextcloud
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: nextcloud
    networks:
      - nextcloud

  app:
    image: nextcloud:25.0.6
    ports:
      - 45080:80
    depends_on:
      - db
      - collabora
    volumes:
      - ./nextcloud:/var/www/html
    restart: always
    networks:
      - nextcloud
    environment:
      - NEXTCLOUD_TRUSTED_DOMAINS=cloud.nextcloud.com

  collabora:
    image: collabora/code
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - nextcloud
    ports:
      - "9980:9980"
    environment:
      - domain=cloud\\.nextcloud\\.com
      - "extra_params=--o:ssl.enable=false  --o:ssl.termination=true"
    tty: true
    cap_add:
      - MKNOD

networks:
  nextcloud:
```

I've also setup with success the like to my local collabora server in nextcloud:

[image]

But for some reason I still can not open any document to edit online, in my test, I can not open the "Welcome to Nextcloud Hub.docx" of this local link http://0.0.0.0:45080/apps/files/?dir=/Documents&openfile=7

[image]

Could any of you tell me what exactly I am missing?

Comment: are you sure that the url http://0.0.0.0:45080/apps/files/?dir=/Documents&openfile=7 is correct? why you are sending a request to `0.0.0.0` host?

Comment: Yes it is correct. 0.0.0.0 or localhost are the same and they are interchangeable one with the other.